# How to make Elasticsearch exists query case insensitive

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using JSON in Java to check if **field exists** in my Elasticsearch database, but I need the exists query to be **case insensitive**. So "color" and "CoLoR" or "COLOR" are being considered the same.

right now I have this:

```
String colFieldExistsJson = jo()
   .put("query", jo()
      .put("bool", jo()
         .put("must", jo()
            .put("exists", jo()
               .put("field", colAttribute))))).toString();
```

But it doesn't find anything if **colAttribute** is **COLOR** since the field is in lowercase.

I tried searching around the internet if somebody already had this problem, but I found nothing and I couldn't find any attributes which I could use with exists query to ensure **case insensitivity**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK I'm not aware of any means to search for case-insensitive fields in Elasticsearch at the moment. Consider two fields with the names "DOG" and "dog." Then it is considered that these two fields are distinct.

You can visit this [GitHub link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/68561) to see the entire conversation that took place on this. This is currently classified as a **high-hanging fruit issue** by Elasticsearch.

Comment: I see, thanks for answering. Looks like I'll need to take different approach.